# Multiple Grails plugins and classpath

Tags: grails, plugins, classpath

I am trying to start a **Grails application** that consists of **multiple plug-ins** each of which is stored as a separate Maven module. Dependencies are specified within `BuildConfig.groovy` files. While starting the app classes (both Java and Groovy) stored in other plugins are not loaded. I've checked the **classpath** and it seems it **does not include classed generated by other plugins**.

Dependencies within `BuildConfig.groovy` look like this:

```
    grails.project.class.dir = "target/classes"
    grails.project.test.class.dir = "target/test-classes"
    grails.project.test.reports.dir = "target/test-reports"

    grails.plugin.location.'plugin-one' = "${basedir}/../plugin-one"
    grails.plugin.location.'plugin-two' = "${basedir}/../plugin-two"

    grails.project.dependency.resolution = {
        inherits("global") {
            excludes 'commons-logging', 'commons-collections'
        }
        log "warn"
        repositories {
            inherit false
            mavenRepo "http://my.maven.repo"
        }
        plugins {
            runtime ':tomcat:1.3.7'
            runtime ':hibernate:1.3.7'
            ...
        }
        dependencies {
            compile "org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.2.1"
            compile "org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:4.2.1"
            compile "commons-collections:commons-collections:3.2.1"

            build "org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.2.1"
            build "org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:4.2.1"
            build "commons-collections:commons-collections:3.2.1"
            ...
        }
    }

    gwt.version = "2.3.0"
```

The structure of Maven modules is as follows:

```
    /pom.xml
    /my-app/pom.xml
    /plugin-one/pom.xml
    /plugin-two/pom.xml
    ...
```

Comment: "stored as separate Maven module" - can you elaborate on this? Is the app you work on mavenized as well?

Comment: Can you share your BuildConfig.groovy?

Comment: @dmahapatro - I have a flat structure of Maven modules: my-app, plugin-one, plugin-two, etc. Although I'm pretty sure this is not the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The grails application **does not** extends its classpath to plugin directories. Instead, all compiled classes are copied into `target/plugin-classes` directory contained by your application base directory.

The problem described in the previous post was caused by **Grails not wanting to copy plug-ins resources** to the application classpath **due to missing Grails plug-in's descriptors**. In particular, `plugin.xml` files. Unfortunately, Grails documentation is silent about that. However, you can generate `plugin.xml` files for all your plugins by invoking `grails package-plugin` command within plugin's base directory. Remember to **regenerate plugin descriptor** after *significant* changes to plugin configuration if you don't want Grails to fail silently.